# Can I find the function of X and Y that best predicts the value of Z given a few data points?

Tags: regression

Given the following data points

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 18.23 | 3 | 80 |
| 42.2 | 5.5 | 600 |
| 377.30 | 52.04 | 900 |
| 6835.86 | 646.91 | 17 000 |

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 250 | 20 | ? |

Can I find the function of X and Y that best predicts the value of Z?

In my (basic) understanding, a multivariate regression will give me the equation of a plane, which is not super precise.

How can I get the equivalent of a polynomial function as the fitting function?
What tool can I use?

Comment: Equation of a plan? Maybe 'plane'. You can take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_interpolation

Comment: @Mateo yes plane, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The points are not close to a plane. If you try to fit a plane the fitting will be bad especially for the low values of z ( if the criteria of fitting is Least Mean Square Error ) . See the next result :

[image]

Since they are only four points one can have an exact fit with any equation on the form

y=a * f1(x) + b * f2(x) + c * f3(x) + d * f4(x)

where f1, f2, f3, f4 are arbitrary undependant functions. Thus they are infinity many solutions.

Among so many solutions why not a very simple one ? For example :

[image]

The result is exact : Perfect fittig.

Comment: Thank you that's amazing! What tool did you use for the computation?

Comment: I need to do the same computation for different values :), can you share the tool you're using?

Comment: There is no need for sophisticated tool since this is a basic linear regression in the first example and a simple solving of system of four linear equations in the second example. What is shown above is the screen copies of the calculus with Mathcad : https://www.mathcad.com/fr .

Comment: ok thanks, went with https://www.desmos.com/matrix